# Show that you've answered another user's question on their profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Would it be possible to add some indication to the *Questions* section of a user's profile page that you've answered a question by that user?  In my minds eye, I see it as a line underneath the "last activity" entry, perhaps showing rep delta or vote count for the answer instead of your total rep (since you already have total rep visible at the top of the page).

Something like this (cobbled together from one of my questions and another page with one of my answers):

[SO answer showing own response to another's question http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/3559/sofeature.png](http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/3559/sofeature.png)

Comment: Could you explain *why* you'd like to see this feature? I can't really think of a good use for this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm opposed. We're supposed to emphasize content over authorship.

Comment: Look, I have my list of, ahem, favorite users, and I'm sure you do, too. But encouraging further attempts to turn the site into a social network, well, seems a bad idea.

Comment: @The Cat: Yeah...ignorance, not malice.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of targ^H^H^H^Hhelping "favorite users"; more on the lines of "I've gained X rep by helping user Y before, encouraging me to help them again".